# Shall I use toHaveBeenCalledTimes in my tests to count how many times dispatch was called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs

I often see my teammates use `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` in their tests with Jest to count how many times the dispatch method of Redux store was called.

It seems useless and redundant for me: if we check that the proper actions were called, why do we need to count the number of calls for the dispatch method?

Looks like this:

`expect(setEnabled).toHaveBeenCalled();
 expect(updateUserData).toHaveBeenCalled();
 expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);`

Does it really make sense to check the number of calls for dispatch method?
Looks like that in such case we don't really test that the function works as appropriate, but test the implementation.

Comment: It could sometimes be important to determine that dispatch was only called a certain number of times if the dispatch results in a side effect or modification of state. Imagine a counter that increments state by one, for example. You would want to make sure that clicking a plus button only incremented the state by one instead of calling the same action twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rare cases, nested or circular dispatch calls can cause unexpected state behavior, but in most cases, `toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` check here is reduntant, if no complex Redux middleware is implemented. However, redundant testing is arguably better than insufficient testing, so it cannot be necessarily concluded that your teammates are doing something wrong.